# Default print margins

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I'm making up a A3 graphic for a client that will be getting printed. The only problem I have is what to use as the default printer clearance margins in the paper.

I assume for the final work it will be best to double check with the printers but is there a guideline/industry default sizing for the margins?

Comment: There isn't an industry default. If you are using a commercial printer, they can do full bleeds at A3 sizes. If the client is specifying who is printing the piece, get the name of the printer and contact them to see if there are any restrictions. There probably aren't any.

Comment: @Voxwoman I did assume they can probably do full bleed but I can't get printers details to double check till next week and was trying to do some early mockup/prototyping just now and just wanted to play it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Voxwoman's comment mentions, **there is no default margin** for a commercial press. Use whatever margin you want, including a full bleed. Full bleeds may increase production costs however.

If considering a home or end-use consumer printer, using 1/4" or 1p6 picas is generally best. You may be able to get away with 1/8" but that's very rare. And some home-use printers require 3/8" on once side for the gripper. Every end-use printer is different. There is no real "universal" standard. If you want to be absolutely safe, 1/2" may be best.